# The most efficient way to search every element of a list in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have a over 1M dataset like d. I need to find indexes of a dataframe like seekingframe which is over 1500 element in that dataset.

```
import pandas as pd 

d=pd.DataFrame([225,230,235,240,245,250,255,260,265,270,275,280,285,290,295,300,305,310,315,320])
seekingframe=pd.DataFrame([275,280,285,290,295,300,305,310,315,320,325,330,335,340,345,350,355,180,255,260])
```

I need to find every element of seekingframe in d as fast as possible. I mean, i need a final array like:

```
array([ 10, 11,  12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6, 7])
```

or the difference array like

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

or sth that denoting the similarities or differences. Actually, if it is possible, i would rather to drop that different sets.

Comment: Are the numbers unique in each dataframe ?

Comment: are the numbers (strictly) monotonic?

Comment: this seems like a numpy problem as well, so tagging that if it is alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely faster to use numpy. On these small unique arrays, numpy was more than 100x faster than pandas `.isin()` without passing `assume_unique=True` to the numpy function that finds the intersection of two arrays ( `np.in1d` ) and returns `True` or `False`.

It was 300x faster if you *did* pass `assume_unique=True`:

```
#finding similar
%timeit d[d[0].isin(seekingframe[0])].index
404 µs ± 6.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#finding difference
%timeit seekingframe[~seekingframe[0].isin(d[0])].index
458 µs ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# finding similar with numpy arrays and NOT passing `assume_unique=True`
a = d[0].to_numpy()
b = seekingframe[0].to_numpy()
%timeit np.arange(a.shape[0])[np.in1d(a, b)]

35.4 µs ± 779 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# finding similar with numpy arrays and passing `assume_unique=True`
a = d[0].to_numpy()
b = seekingframe[0].to_numpy()
%timeit np.arange(a.shape[0])[np.in1d(a, b, assume_unique=True)]

12 µs ± 337 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```